# Search query logging in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

The users can search 'Search queries' in SharePoint online Microsoft intelligence search in a SharePoint site collection. Can we get a search query report(any other SharePoint log for the search queries) in that particular site collection only?

Image:[Image of MS Intelligent search in SharePoint online](https://cdn.ttgtmedia.com/rms/onlineImages/ContentManagement_SharePoint_example_AI_search_results_mobile.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [popularity and search reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/classic-usage-popularity-reports-discontinued) in the site settings for now. And it is retiring, the new [search usage reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports) will take the place where you can check the Top Queries.

Comment: I check this but These reports only have data on searches that users perform using classic search, not the modern (intelligent) search. refer: https://sharepointmaven.com/what-are-users-searching-for-in-your-sharepoint-intranet/